# Forward declarations in anonymous namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

A common pattern I use is to declare functions in a namespace (typically in a `.h` file) and then implement the function separately (typically in a `.cxx` file), naming the namespace at the point of implementation.  For example:

```
namespace foo {
    void bar(int x);
}
...
foo::bar(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
```

This works great, but if I try following a similar pattern for anonymous namespaces (putting both declaration and definition in the same `.cxx` file, of course), it doesn't work:

```
namespace {
    void bar(int x);
}
...
void bar(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
```

This produces errors at link time because the function's implementation is implementing `::bar(int)`, not `(anonymous)::foo(int)`.

There are no problems doing this with types, classes and variable declarations, because they end up fully defined in the namespace and are made public with an implicit `using` directive.  But for a function, subsequent implementations use the global namespace, not the one implicitly copied from the anonymous namespace.

I realize that I can put the function's implementation in another anonymous namespace block and they will correctly be associated with each other:

```
namespace {
    void bar(int x);
}
...
namespace {
    void bar(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
}
```

This works, but I think it makes the code look a bit ugly - the entire function ends up indented (due to the braces).  This is fine if it's a relatively small function, but ugly and awkward to read if it's a big function.

Ideally, I'd like some equivalent to what I do with a named namespace, where I can just put something on the single line with the start of the function's implementation, but I don't know of any valid syntax that would do this.

I could, of course, just declare the function to be static and forget the use of an anonymous namespace.  But is there a way to do this using namespaces?

Comment: I am not convinced about use-case for having anonymous namespace with declarations in header file, since in my understanding they are two features which contradict each other. Declarations in headers are public interface of given object file (symbols that are exposed for the linker). Anonymous namespaces (and `static`) are used to mark given symbols as private/implementation detail, which are not exposed for the linker. Can it even work properly?

Comment: _"the entire function ends up indented"_ - that depends entirely on how you've chosen to indent your namespaces.

Comment: Of course, the anonymouse use-case requires everything to be in a single file.  I thought I made that clear.  Using two files can only work when the namespace is named.

Comment: *"This is fine if it's a relatively small function, but ugly and awkward to read if it's a big function"* - I really wanna know the exact indentation style you are following. Do you unindent the second line of a function?

Comment: Indentation is very relative and personal, unless you must follow coding standards... For my part, I always indent namespaces in headers, and I never indent within sources, to avoid this problem. So instead of prefixing all function/method explicitely with the namespace, I just declare the namespace again all around the CPP and I still start my functions at first column - however, I never use the `using namespace XXX;` instruction but in very, very rare occasions (test, faulty framework, ...). Also, I never use anonymous namespaces - annoying AF, like you just find it.

Comment: *"the entire function ends up indented"* -- hmm... as an experiment, I plugged `c++ coding style namespace indentation` into Google. One of the top four hits was a question about style; the other three were style guides from [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Namespace_Formatting), [WebKit](https://webkit.org/code-style-guidelines/#indentation-namespace), and [LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#namespace-indentation). The three style guides agree that the contents of namespaces should not be indented. Your question has validity, but one premise seems off.

Comment: To be a little clearer: indenting the contents of a namespace is a valid option. (In fact, one of the styles I like calls for the contents of anonymous namespaces to be indented, to make it easier to determine at a glance what is local to the file and what is not.) However, the question assumes that indenting is the only valid option, which is not the case. There is value in acknowledging discarded options, such as the option of not indenting at the namespace level.

Comment: Like you say, static functions would work. Anonymous namespaces were introduced as a solution to C++98's strict requirements on template parameters (local names not allowed), and some uses of `static` was deprecated. Later the template rules have been relaxed, and use of `static` is now "undeprecated". So, why not give it a try? :-)